# flask-sqlalchemy count function

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Consider a table named `result` with the following schema

```
+----+-----+---------+
| id | tag | user_id |
+----+-----+---------+
|  0 | A   |       0 |
|  1 | A   |       0 |
|  2 | B   |       0 |
|  3 | B   |       0 |
+----+-----+---------+
```

for user with `id=0` I would like to count they number of times a result with `tag=A` has been appeared. For now I have implemented it using raw SQL statement

```
db.session.execute('select tag, count(tag) from result where user_id = :id group by tag', {'id':user.id})
```

How can I write it using *flask-sqlalchemy* APIs?
Most of results I get mention the *sqlalchemy* function `db.func.count()` which is not available in *flask-sqlalchemy* or has a different path which I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using `PyCharm` as my IDE and it was not showing module members correctly, hence I thought `count` is missing. Here is my solution for the above

```
user.results.add_columns(Result.tag, db.func.count(Result.tag)).group_by(Result.tag).all()
```